# Can windows server 2012 be installed on virtual box?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

Im trying to install windows server 2012 on virtual box via a bootable usb but it just reaches to this screen and hangs indefinitely, I've allocated 2GB of RAM and 15GB of space for the virtual HDD, not getting any error messages just stuck at this screen.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the correct window you're on. Have you tried closing the alerts on top?
Maybe the **press any key to boot.....** is behind those alerts?

And give atleast 3 GB ram to run smoothly

Comment: Because of the limitations of my system i am only allowed to give it 2GB of RAM max. and i have tried closing the alerts but there isn't anything behind them.